# JGit - Create Merge Requests through Java

Tags: java, gitlab, jgit

Looking through the JGit API for a way to create a **Merge Request** in GItlab. Is there a way to get it done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Merge request** or **Pull Request** is not a GIT specific feature, so its natural there is no available way to create one using JGit.

What you can do however is use the [Rest API from Github](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#create-a-pull-request) to create a pull request from your Java code. I am not sure whether you are using Github though, but popular Git repositories do have such an API which you can utilize to create a merge request.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am using GitLabee.

Comment: Gitlab also has a public api for [Merge requests](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html)

Comment: Can you please share some sample code to get a Quick Start?

Comment: You can use this [library](https://github.com/gitlab4j/gitlab4j-api) for interfacing with gitlab. There's this class named MergeRequestApi which may fit your use case.